# Slicing a data.frame in Actual Parameter Causes Error

Tags: r

The following has been keeping me busy for days.

```
require( tree )
subset <- 1:nrow( iris )
formula <- as.formula( "Species ~ ." )

iris <- iris[ subset, ]
tfit <- tree( formula = formula, data = iris )
mclass <- cv.tree( object = tfit, FUN = prune.misclass )

tfit <- tree( formula = formula, data = iris[ subset, ] )
mclass <- cv.tree( object = tfit, FUN = prune.misclass )
```

The last call to `cv.tree` throws an error:

```
Error in xj[i] : invalid subscript type 'closure'
```

I would have thought the two constructions of `tfit` and `mclass` were equivalent. What am I missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a scoping issue. `cv.tree` finds the `subset` function instead of the `subset` vector. This is what the error message tells you; `'closure'` is a type of function.

The issue can be fixed by renaming the `subset` vector, but this is a bug which should be reported to the package maintainer.